# What should be the colour of Button in html after making disabled?

Tags: html, css

I am writing this line of code;

```
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" class="configurationButton" id="btnAddButton" style="width:60px;" name="btnAddButton" value="Add" disabled>
```

When it loads, button becomes Disabled but its color is still black. As there is default black color in .configurationButton , , ,
 Please tell me what the color of Disable Button in above tag example should be?

Comment: It doesn't matter, there is no 'standard' for this, they're *usually*, but not mandated to be, greyed out, but they can just as easily be neon pink and green.

Comment: @DavidThomas; actually, I am working in IE-10, in ie-9, it becomes Grey(Silver). I want same output in IE10. One thing what I have also observed that in CSS there is a class .configurationButton, in it color:#333333 is specified. In IE-9 it is not applynig and button becomes Silver but in IE10 it is applying. What can I do to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the JS fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Usj5Q/

```
.configurationButton
{
    background:black;
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.configurationButton:disabled
{
    background:white;
    color:gray;
    cursor:default;
    opacity:0.2;
```

}

Comment: Thnk YOu [AB] ... Problem Solved:)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally disabled button should look like grayed out. You can check out this URL, if your want to know what should be the style of buttons in various states - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-buttons.php

Comment: Thanks [Alax Menon] I am working in IE-10, in ie-9, it becomes Grey(Silver). I want same output in IE10. One thing what I have also observed that in CSS there is a class .configurationButton, in it color:#333333 is specified. In IE-9 it is not applynig and button becomes Silver but in IE10 it is applying. What can I do to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

the look and feel of input tags aren't specified by the HTML standard. Each browser and each  desktop environment has their own look and feel.